# SSHFS mount marked all files as hidden

Tags: ftp, file-permissions, sshfs, chown, iis-8

I ran

```
chown -R me:me /opt/web/ftp-mounts/
```

which affected files on sshfs ftp mounts. The remote server hosts IIS based websites. I might have messed up the file permissions on the remote host.

Now when I request static files on my production website, I get IIS error

```
HTTP Error 404.9 - Not Found
This error occurs when the requested file is marked as hidden on the file system.
```

How do I revert these? I just messed up my production server!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
chmod -R 777
```

solved the issue.

Comment: while manual pages for `chown` never mention messing with access bits, apparently windows servers have their own policy, and do mess with access bits on `chown`. That's fairly logical, when one considers windows security.

Comment: As further follow up, because of this, my boss banned use of *nix company-wide. I'm now back to doing it, but covertly :D

Comment: now instead of keeping these same mounts in  /opt/ftp-mounts/* i keep them in /keep_safe/* :)